# Android app randomly closes without any error

Tags: android

I'm currently working on a pretty big music app. And for some reason, my app randomly closes, without any error message.

I catch uncaught exceptions in the project using the following code:

```java
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {...});
```

but even if it works every time for obvious exceptions, I don't catch any error when the app closes by itself. Also, it's not device related, since I tried on 10 differents devices of different brands with different versions of Android.

My question is: has anyone experienced something similar and if yes, what was the solution of your problem? Or, in other words: is there any case where an Android app can close by itself without any error (and without using System.exit())

I know it's not a very specific question, but since I have no idea where it comes from, I can't do any better so far.

Comment: Do you have a github repository that we coul have a look at your code?

Comment: No unfortunately, and it's a 60K+ lines of code project, so that'll be too long to process...

Comment: But I just wonder if there is any case where an Android app can close by itself without any error (and without using System.exit()).

Answer (score 0):

The default uncaught handler yo are overriding are the responsible to display the error to the user, the solution is to have a reference to the old one and call it on yours as follow:

```
final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler appDefault = Thread.GetDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
   public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
      // DO STUFF BEFORE APP CRASHES
      appDefault.uncaughtException(t, e); // call later, so the app crashes as default
   }});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. Not sure it will solve my problem, though.